# Write into custom configsection in a configuration file from C#

Tags: c#, config, custom-sections

I have a configuration file like this:

```
<configSections>

    <section
        name="environmentVariables"
        type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=234effdfsdfdf" />

</configSections>

<environmentVariables>
    <add key="xxx" value="yyyy" />
    <add key="zz" value="ddd" />
</environmentVariables>
```

I need to change the values of key "xxx" and "zz" during runtime from C#.

I have accessed the file using the code below:

```
string configPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/files/temp.config");
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = configPath;
System.Configuration.Configuration config = 
    ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Comment: What is your config file ? Is it app.config or web.config or your own custom config (xml) file ?

Comment: its a custom config file at a particular location. 
I have updated the question.plz check

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("YourKey", "YourValue");
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
```

Source: [Write values in app.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758598/write-values-in-app-config-file)

Comment: This will add the value into <appSettings> .But I need to edit value in custom config section . In my case the <environmentVariables>.

Comment: @NeenoXavier what about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774358/c-sharp-set-environment-variable ?

Comment: <environmentVariables> is just a name given to the section. It can be anything like <mySettings>