# C# dllImport and Environment Variables

Tags: java, c#, variables, dllimport, environment

This is a tough one to explain, but I will do my best.
I writing a C# program and am using DLLImport to access Unmanaged Code in an external C++ DLL.
The C++ DLL is a wrapper to a java program.
I can only get it to work if I call my C# program is called within a DOS batch file that sets various Environment Variables that are required by the C++/Java external functions.
I want to be able to not use a DOS batch file and set and control the Environment Variables withing my C# program.
Seeking tips form anyone as I have not found a way to do this, or know if it even possible.
Thanks.

Comment: This cannot be done because each .NET application gets its own "cache" of the environment variables. These are isolated from the OS. Further, even when using the native P/Invoke call to set the environment variables, that "cache" is not updated. This means that the stack in which the application is launched will not see those changes.

Comment: I know you have stated that this cannot be done, but when I run my application as administrator, the DLL calls all work. So they appear to have access to the User Environment variables that are set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's about

```
public static void SetEnvironmentVariable(
    string variable,
    string value,
     EnvironmentVariableTarget targer
)
```

This function sets Enviroment variable

```
using System
....
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(envName, envValue,EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

Look example at msdn
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: Thanks for this. I am already using the code shown to set environemnt variables. However this does not seem to be my problem. When I call the functions declared with DLLImport, they only appear to work when I run my applciation as administrator.

Comment: Did you try to use SetEnvironmentVariable with tree parameters `public static void SetEnvironmentVariable( string variable, string value, EnvironmentVariableTarget target )` where you can set variable target: `Machine,Process,User` ???

Comment: Yes I have. When I set target as user, the user Enviroment Varialbes cahnge as I set them. Process does not do anything, and machine fails with permission issue. Just to point out again, these calls are all working, it is the exteranl DLL I am calling that does not work. If I set all Environment variables in a batch file and call the application it works, and if I run my application as administrator (without batch file) it also works. The problem appears to be the accessability of the Environment Variables to the external DLL that I am calling.

Comment: I think I am getting close to getting this working. All you have shown is working, but the issue I think is due the setting the enviroment variable 'PATH". After I run my application I check the user environment variables and they are all set correctly. The PATH=%PATH%;C:\SomeOtherPath\ , BUT when I go to the DOS prompt and recall them, the PATH returns me the System Enviroment Vaible and not the USer one. This maybe my issue. So am still looking how to sort this.

Comment: Using the info provided to me above and the other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774358/c-sharp-set-environment-variable, I was able to get my program all working. Using the EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process worked in the end, there was an issue with PATH, which was sorted by NOT using %PATH%, but setting explicitly with GetEnvironmentVariable function and

Comment: Working code example:
string NEW_DIR = @"C:\AnyOldPath";                
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + ";" + NEW_DIR + @"\Bin", envt);                
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SPECIAL_LIB_PATH", NEW_DIR + @"\Lib\", envt);

Comment: It's a good decision to use GetEnvironmentVariable. Best Regards