# How to set path of .dll file from windows form application project in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, dll

I'm making a Windows Form project in MS Visual Studio 2012 and using an external .dll file.
However, to use the functions of that file, i need to set the path of that .dll file in Environment Variables PATH option manually.

> My Computer -> Properties -> Advance System Settings -> Environment Variables -> PATH

Can i do something in my code that when i give someone the generated .exe setup file of my application alongwith .dll file, my application automatically sets the path of .dll file from application directory?

If this question is repeated, kindly provide me with the link for my answer.

Comment: SET DEVPATH=C:\path\to\dlls;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set environment variables from c# code by using `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`
Have a look here: [C# set environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774358/c-sharp-set-environment-variable)