# C# WPF Set System variable Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, variables

So what i'm trying to do is in my WPF application saving values of variables in system variables to make it accesible for other scripts.

```
temperature = (detection as Temperature).MeasurementValueCelsius;

string value;
value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TemperatureDERMA");

value = temperature.ToString();
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TemperatureDERMA", value);
```

I already tries generating the variable "TemperatureDERMA" manually in windows in case maybe it could't generate a new variable. But still for some reason I couldn't get it set to my specific value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3oVa.png)

I debugged in visual studio and it says that the variable "value" gets the right value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143212/environment-setenvironmentvariable-not-working)

Comment: What do you call *scripts*? If my suspicions correct, you are falling into [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295). Tell us what you are trying to achieve, there might be a more suitable way.

Comment: Please don't do this. Environment variables are not meant to be used in this manner.

Comment: We are linking with SCALA, a digital signage platform. So we have python scripts that are used to detect variable changes.

Comment: @IanKemp What would you suggest then?

Comment: @Sinatr I already saw this thread and tried it! But still no effect :/

Comment: Since you're trying to talk between Python and WPF your best bet is probably sockets. Your Python app will open a socket on a specific port and listen on it, your WPF app will open a socket using the same port and write to it.

Comment: @IanKemp any references to get me started?