# Environment variable, PowerShell session vs. started from CMD

Tags: powershell, variables, cmd, environment

I am trying to run a PowerShell command from within a command prompt window (run as Administrator), but it fails. Whereas when I run the same command from within a PowerShell window it runs fine.

**Here is the command without error in a PowerShell window:**

```
Powershell [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HostIPv4", "192.168.255.14:", "Machine")
```

**In the command prompt window it fails:**

```
C:\test>powershell [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HostIPv4", "192.168.255.14:", "Machine")
At line:1 char:39
+ [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(HostIPv4, 192.168.255.14:, Mach ...
+                                       ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:1 char:39
+ [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(HostIPv4, 192.168.255.14:, Mach ...
+                                       ~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'HostIPv4' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:47
+ [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(HostIPv4, 192.168.255.14:, Mach ...
+                                               ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At line:1 char:73
+ ... ironment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(HostIPv4, 192.168.255.14:, Machine)
+                                                                         ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is there a reason to do this with PowerShell and not `SETX`?

Comment: Well, I know that the target machines that I need this for always have Powershell available. PS do not have to be approved for use on the machines. Setx would have to be approved for use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell's command-line parsing removes the double quotes, try using single quotes:

```
powershell [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('HostIPv4', '192.168.255.14:', 'Machine')
```

Also note that you have to reopen an new process window to see the results (this is a known behavior for the command shell, see also: [C# set environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774358/c-sharp-set-environment-variable))

Comment: Thank you, Iron, for this answer. So simple and so effectful - kind of embarrassed that I did not think of it myself. It works!

Answer (score 3):

**[iRon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44827561/45375) explains the problem and works**, but I suggest adopting **a generally more robust approach to invoking PowerShell commands from `cmd.exe`**:

- **Use `-Command`** explicitly, because in PSv6 the default will change to `-File`, expecting a *script* filename rather than a command.
- **Use `-NoProfile`**, to avoid unnecessary loading of the PowerShell profiles and for a more predictable execution environment.
- ***Double-quote* your *entire* PowerShell command** to protect it from potentially unwanted up-front interpretation by `cmd.exe`.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('HostIPv4', '192.168.255.14:', 'Machine')"
```

The use of `'` instead of `"` *inside* the command string is an easy way to avoid having to *escape* embedded `"` characters, which works fine here, but in case you do need embedded `"` (for interpolating strings), escape them either as `\"` (sic) or `"""` (sic).

Comment: Thank you, mklement0, I will look into your recommendations. my immediate problem solved. Thanks again.